# LibreOffice Calc performance tuning

Tags: libreoffice-calc, performance-tuning

I have 350 thousand rows in a LibreOffice Calc table (it's a 35 meg [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file). I only need to view it, not edit it. Yet, it is very slow at scrolling, filtering, and selecting the cells. What can I disable besides the spell check to speed things up? Also, how do I disable spell check properly (if that is the bottleneck)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spreadsheet is probably not the optimal application for viewing a CSV file of that size.  I believe you'll have a better viewing experience if you use the CSV file as a datasource for a LibreOffice [Base](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) file.

When you start up Base, choose to "connect to an existing database" and choose "Text" from the dropdown box of database types.  Click "Next", press the "Browse" button to choose the folder your file is saved in (not the file itself, just the folder), select the radio button for "comma separated value files", customize the separator characters if needed, press "Next" and choose whether or not you want to register the database inside LibreOffice (if you want to use other LibreOffice components like Writer or Calc to be "standalone forms" for viewing the data, you will have to register; otherwise it doesn't matter whether you register or not; you can always register later if you don't do it here).

Press "Finish", choose a name and save location for your Base file, and it will open with your CSV data inside a "Table".  Double-click the table name (same as your CSV file name) and you can view the data.  It should be much faster than your experience in Calc.